# Hide object-ids in Node.js (MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Following is the response of a GET request:

```
{
    "parkingList": [
        {
            "_id": "62e11ab3079daa939290fa07",
            "parkingInfo": [
                {
                    "parkingName": "Fountain Avenue",
                    "default": [],
                    "_id": "62e11ab3079daa939290fa0f"
                }
            ],
            "availability": [
                {
                    "day": "Tuesday",
                    "startTime": "08:00",
                    "endTime": "16:00",
                    "_id": "62e11ab3079daa939290fa0b"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
}
```

I don't want to show the parkingInfo._id and availability._id.

I have tried the following query but still I am getting the ids.

```
let parkings = await Parking.find(
      {
        "location.city": req.body.city,
      },
      {
        availability: {
          $elemMatch: { day: startTime },
        },
        parkingInfo: 1,
      }
    ).select(
      "-createdAt -updatedAt -__v -parkingInfo._id -availability._id -userId" // Here is what I have tried.
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because you stated  `parkingInfo: 1,` which says to project the whole parkingInfo object, you have to specify all the fields of parkingInfo separatedly as follow:

```
ParkingModel.find({},
{
  availability: {
    $elemMatch: { day: "Tuesday" },
  },
  parkingInfo: {
    "_id":0
  },
  availability: {
    "_id":0
  },
}
).select(
"-createdAt -updatedAt -__v -userId" // Here is what I have tried.
)
```

Comment: Ok It is working good but is there any other alternative because I have lots of field to show. I am passing every single variable name separately and it became quite lengthy

Comment: And What about ```availability._Id```

Comment: i have updated the code, now it is hiding the ids, when you assign 0 for a field, it means hide it and show the others